# Theme for my WiX Installer

Tags: wix

I have seen WiX doing wonders in creating an msi which adopts to the current theme of windows. My curiosity is that whether we can hard code any theme for WiX. Whether we can design the look and feel. Is there any link where somebody has tried it and put their code for others to learn ??

Regards,

tvks

Answer (score 2):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/07/23/442584.aspx - if you want to do advanced UI stuff you'll need to build an external UI. The internal/standard Windows Installer UI is pretty limited.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the bitmap images to change the themes.

Update the wixvariable WixUIBannerBmp with the image you want and then use the id on each screen

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Bitmaps\bannrbmp.bmp" Overridable="no"/>
```