# How do I pass a default 'install location' to the RtfLicense bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, wix3.6, bootstrapper

I'm using an rtflicence standard bootstrapper to install dotnet before my poject msi in a chain.

I noticed that there's an 'options' button which displays an install location dialog and allows the user to change the default installation directory.

I need to either:

1. Prevent this options button from being displayed, or
2. Populate the install location with a default path, and pass this back to the installer should the user change it.

I read that it's possible to pass Burn variables to msipackages from bootstrapper but I haven't found any further details and would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To go with option 1, you'd have to roll your own BootstrapperApplication and remove the options button from the menu.

Option two is significantly easier to implement. The bootstrapper uses a special Burn variable called `InstallFolder` to get and set what is in the text block on that view, which you can assign inside the `Bundle` element.

```
<Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]"/>
```

The constant `ProgramFilesFolder` will set the value of that text block when the program starts, and if the user browses to a different directory, it will be stored in that same variable. To pass it to the MSI, in your chain, you pass the `InstallFolder` using the `MsiProperty` tag (`INSTALLLOCATION` is the name of the property in your WiX project).

```
<MsiPackage Vital="yes" DisplayName="Your Name" Id="MsiId" SourceFile="path/to/file.msi">
    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
</MsiPackage>
```

Answer (score 18):

I just discovered the SuppressOptionsUI option that addresses your Option 1 without rolling your own BootstrapperApplication:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">

   <Bundle>
      <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
         <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="..\eula.rtf" SuppressOptionsUI="yes"/>
      </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

      <Chain>
      </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try removing the options button by creating a theme. I haven't had to use themes myself but here are two related SO links that may get you pointed in that direction:

[WiX bootstrapper theme file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931008/wix-bootstrapper-theme-file)

[Theme for my WiX Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625520/theme-for-my-wix-installer)